# How to parse text with ansible using a nested list/dict?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a text file that needs to be parsed so i can use it via a REST API with ansible.

```
10.0.0.0/16 Building-A
10.1.0.0/16 Building-A
10.2.0.0/16 Building-B
10.3.0.0/16 Building-B
```

I need to convert this text to something like this:

```json
{
   "parsed":[
      {
         "Building-A":[
            "10.0.0.0/16",
            "10.1.0.0/16"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Building-B":[
            "10.2.0.0/16",
            "10.3.0.0/16"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Currently i run the following playbook to test the textparsing, without success. The list created is not unique.

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: Combine
     ansible.builtin.set_fact:
       parsed: "{{ (parsed | default([])) | union( [{item.split()[1]: item.split()[0] }] ) }}"
     loop: "{{ lookup('file','hostgroups.txt').strip().splitlines() }}"

   - name: Debug
     ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: parsed
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "parsed": [
        {
            "Building-A": "10.0.0.0/16"
        },
        {
            "Building-A": "10.1.0.0/16"
        },
        {
            "Building-B": "10.2.0.0/16"
        },
        {
            "Building-B": "10.3.0.0/16"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for the tip with the helper variables and the groupby filter. Here is the final playbook:

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
#  strategy: free
  tasks:
   - name: Get List
     ansible.builtin.set_fact:
       parsed_list: "{{ parsed_list | default([]) + [_item] }}"
     loop: "{{ lookup('file','hostgroups.txt').strip().splitlines() }}"
     vars:
       _list: "{{ item.split() }}"
       _item: "{{ {'Name': _list[1], 'Subnet': _list[0] } }}"

   - name: Debug parsed_list
     ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: parsed_list

   - name: Group parsed_list
     ansible.builtin.set_fact.set_fact:
      parsed_group: "{{ parsed_group | default([]) + [{_key: _value}] }}"
     loop: "{{ parsed_list | groupby('Name') }}"
     vars:
       _key: "{{ item.0 }}"
       _value: "{{ item.1 | map(attribute='Subnet') | list }}"

   - name: Debug parsed_group
     ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: parsed_group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the content, e.g.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      parsed_list: "{{ parsed_list|d([]) + [_item] }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('file','hostgroups.txt').splitlines() }}"
    vars:
      _array: "{{ item.split() }}"
      _item: "{{ {'building': _array.1, 'ip': _array.0} }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  parsed_list:
  - building: Building-A
    ip: 10.0.0.0/16
  - building: Building-A
    ip: 10.1.0.0/16
  - building: Building-B
    ip: 10.2.0.0/16
  - building: Building-B
    ip: 10.3.0.0/16
```

Then, use filter [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby) and create the list

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      parsed: "{{ parsed|d([]) + [{_key: _val}] }}"
    loop: "{{ parsed_list|groupby('building') }}"
    vars:
      _key: "{{ item.0 }}"
      _val: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='ip')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  parsed:
  - Building-A:
    - 10.0.0.0/16
    - 10.1.0.0/16
  - Building-B:
    - 10.2.0.0/16
    - 10.3.0.0/16
```

---

In some cases, a dictionary might be a better structure, e.g.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      parsed_dict: "{{ parsed_dict|d({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
    loop: "{{ parsed_list|groupby('building') }}"
    vars:
      _key: "{{ item.0 }}"
      _val: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='ip')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  parsed_dict:
    Building-A:
    - 10.0.0.0/16
    - 10.1.0.0/16
    Building-B:
    - 10.2.0.0/16
    - 10.3.0.0/16
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick with a second loop and the groupby filter. Marked as answered.